# My JavaScript code is memory leaking, but I don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory-leaks

I have a Discord bot written in Nodejs (JavaScript), but I run into a memory leak issue recently.

My code is using ~10GB memory, and it keep increasing. I run `process.memUsage()` and it returned something like this:

```
rss: ~10GB
heapTotal: ~300MB
heapUsed: ~250MB
external: ~500MB
arrayBuffer: ~500MB
```

I can't figure out which piece of code is leaking, there is alot tool that will diagnose memory leak in Node.js, but almost all tools is watching `heap` instead `rss`.

> Note: I did not use any `var` keyword, I hate it.

Code repository: https://github.com/blackcatbot/blackcat

Comment: Please include the directly related code in your post. Linking to an external repo is not well looked on.

Comment: But my code is very huge, how can I include code in this post?

Comment: Hmmm, I wouldn't like to venture that this would be out of scope for SO, but I'm not sure how you'll get an answer here. It'll be hard to find people who'll be willing to go through all that and debug for you. Try including something the more suspicious areas of your code.

Comment: There is no any suspicious area in my code, I reviewed my code multiple times yesterday, and I found nothing.

Comment: Do some heap snapshots and find the objects that shouldn't be there